# What is the type of fn()?

Tags: rust

```
fn hello(x: u32) {}
```

This can be described as a function taking an integer and returning a `()` (called "Unit"). Great got it! `()` is the default type returned by a function which omits the return type in it's definition.

```
fn hello() -> u32 { 0 }
```

How would you describe this function? A function which takes a ___ and returns an int. A function taking 0 parameters, which returns an int? In C we would have said "void", but as far as I'm aware this is really what `unit` replaces in Rust and other modern languages.

This gets more confusing when I start to look at the Fn trait, which is declared as:

```
pub trait Fn<Args>: FnMut<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

But I can avoid passing anything for Args when using it, e.g. `Fn()`. How is that possible?

How do I explain this consistently? It would have been super clear if in the second example hello() -> u32 actually meant a function which took a `()` and returned an integer. E.g. the default parameter type being consistent with the default return type (which is `()`).

Comment: `fn hello() -> u32 { 0 }` *does not take `()`*, which can be checked by trying to call `hello( () )` . Probably [this doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html) answers most of your questions

Comment: Thanks! I totally know that (kind of the point of the whole question) - so what does it take then? Void? Nothing? Zero arguments? I don't think you understood my question - how can i improve it?

Comment: "0 parameters" sounds right. Imagine `fn hello(x: u32, y: u32)` and the same template template, "a function that takes _____"? Your template just doesn't work for any functions that don't take exactly one argument.

Comment: Yeah totally got you - however my question is aimed at describing the function at the type-level. According to the excellent answers posted, the correct answer is that functions do indeed take a single parameter, which is a tuple of 0 or more types. This is seen clearly in the definition of `trait Fn`, which takes a single `Args`, and returns a single `Output`. `Args` being specified as `()` means an empty tuple. Therefore `Fn() -> u32` describes a function taking zero parameters and returning an int. It would have been way more obvious had it been `Fn(()) -> u32` in my opinion, but hey!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It would have been super clear if in the second example `hello() -> u32` actually meant a function which took a `()` and returned an integer.

Here's the thing: *it does!* But only in the implementation.

> This gets more confusing when I start to look at the Fn trait, which
> is declared as:
>
> ```rust
> pub trait Fn<Args>: FnMut<Args> {
>     extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
> }
> ```
>
> But I can avoid passing anything for Args when using it, e.g. `Fn()`.
> How is that possible?

Whenever `Fn` is used, `Args` is *always a tuple.*

- If the function takes zero parameters, the type is `()` (the tuple with zero elements): `Fn<()>`.
- If the function takes one parameter of type `u32`, the type is `(u32,)` (the rarely-seen tuple with exactly one element): `Fn<(u32,)>`.
- If the function takes two parameters of type `u32`, the type is `(u32, u32)`: `Fn<(u32, u32)>`.

And so on. We don't usually see the one-element tuple type, or think of `()` as a zero-element tuple, but this is the exact kind of place where it makes everything consistent — such as by making the function trait with 1 parameter of type `()` (whose `Args` type is `((),)`) distinct from the function type with 0 parameters (whose `Args` type is `()`).

All that said, you should note that the definition of the `Fn` trait's `call` method is *unstable*, as is the syntax `Fn<()>` (the compiler will tell you to write the special `Fn()` syntax instead), and the primary reason for this is that the Rust language team has not yet decided for certain that they want to continue to define arguments in the way I've described above. They may instead decide to use *variadic generics*, where each function parameter's type is a separate *type parameter* for the trait, i.e. `Fn<u32, u32>` for two parameters. This decision has not yet been made.

Comment: This answers it for me comprehensively, and I appreciate the background on the Fn<()> syntax providing some of the context for the current syntax. Great insight!

Answer (score 3):

> How would you describe this function? A function which takes a ___ and returns an int. A function taking 0 parameters, which returns an int? In C we would have said "void", but as far as I'm aware this is really what `unit` replaces in Rust and other modern languages.

I don't think it would be correct to say that that function takes "void" in C either. Sure, we can declare the function as `int hello(void)`, but that's an arcane syntax to begin with.

In C (ignoring functions that take a variable `...` argument), a function takes a set, finite number of arguments and returns either zero or one values. If the function returns zero values, we write `void` as the return type, which is fundamentally different than returning something. It truly is a special case in C. On the other hand, writing `int hello(void)` is no different, albeit less readable, than `int hello()`. It really is just a function of zero arguments. The `void` is immaterial here; it added nothing to the language in this position.

Now, back to Rust. In Rust, in an effort to be more consistent and remove the awkward special-case that is `void`, a function in Rust is defined to take a set, finite number of arguments and return *exactly* one thing. Always. That one thing might be `()`, the unit type, which we use by convention when we don't need to return any actual information. But it's still there. It's not a special case. If the Rust devs have forgotten to include `()`, I could just as easily write

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct MyUnit;
```

And now I have a type that, all things considered, behaves pretty similarly to `()`. I couldn't do that with `void`. There's no way a user can make an equivalent to `void`. One is a special case and the other is an ordinary type.

On the other hand, just like in C, in Rust a function *can* take zero arguments. So `fn hello() -> u32 { 0 }` is a function that takes zero arguments. It doesn't take a `()`. Nobody is requiring that our function take at least one argument, so we can just say it took zero. In return position, a Rust function *must* always return something, so we fill that something in with `()` when we don't want it, but we have no reason to do so in argument position.

You'll see some languages like OCaml take this even further. In OCaml, *every* function takes exactly one argument and returns exactly one value. There's no "zero or more" on the argument side. So in OCaml, you *will* actually see people write functions that take the `unit` type as an argument (such functions are commonly called "thunks" and are treated as delayed computations). That's because in OCaml the rules require us to have an argument *and* a result. (If you want to take multiple arguments, you either take a tuple, or more commonly you [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the arguments)

---

Note: I use OCaml as an example here rather than Haskell. Haskell has the same "everything takes one argument" restriction, but non-strict evaluation makes the analogy a bit more dubious. In Haskell, you would never write a function whose type is `() -> Int`, since you could just write an `Int` and get the same behavior. That's not true in strict languages like OCaml and Rust, where the very act of invoking the function with its argument can create side effects.

Comment: Let me be a bit of a nitpicker. In C `hello()` means "that is a function, but I will not tell you the arguments it takes"; while `hello(void)` means "hellp is a function that takes no arguments". You may be thinking about C++ where `hello(void)` is indeed redundand, but in C it is not more arcane than the language itself.

Comment: Thanks - great background on the unit/void debate (I'm a Haskeller myself, so was looking to build a bridge across to understand how Rust dealt with these).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would describe `fn hello() -> u32 { 0 }` as a *"function that takes no parameters and returns a `u32`"*.

---

The `Fn` trait is syntactically similar and used like `Fn() -> u32`. What you see for its definition is an implementation detail. Rust traits are not variadic so they can't support varying number of arguments needed to describe function signatures. What is done is that all the arguments are combined in a tuple type. So in this way, a zero-parameter function type is expressed like `Fn<(), Output=u32>`. Just the same as a multi-parameter `Fn` would be expressed like `Fn<(u32, u32), Output=u32>`. However, you should not use that syntax, it is not stabilized. Use `Fn(u32, u32) -> u32` to express your `Fn` trait constraints.